# Does SQL Server Offer Anything Like MySQL's ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql

In MySQL, if you specify [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row is performed. For example, if column a is declared as UNIQUE and contains the value 1, the following two statements have identical effect:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;

UPDATE table SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1;
```

I don't believe I've come across anything of the like in T-SQL. Does SQL Server offer anything comparable to MySQL's ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Comment: You can simulate it with a stored procedure.  I don't have the exact code off the top of my head.

Comment: @Robert Harvey - I've always performed with operation by checking if the row exists. If yes, then perform an update else insert a new row. Is that what you were thinking as well?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There's no DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE equivalent, but MERGE and WHEN MATCHED might work for you

[Inserting, Updating, and Deleting Data by Using MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: Just be aware that MERGE is not immune to high-concurrency insert collision. You **must** use WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) for merge to not collide. Some ultra-high-transaction-per-second systems use a different strategy where the locks are not used, but any errors are trapped and then converted to an update.

Answer (score 66):

I was surprised that none of the answers on this page contained an example of an actual query, so here you go:

A more complex example of inserting data and then handling duplicate

```
MERGE
INTO MyBigDB.dbo.METER_DATA WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target
USING (SELECT
    77748 AS rtu_id
   ,'12B096876' AS meter_id
   ,56112 AS meter_reading
   ,'20150602 00:20:11' AS time_local) AS source
(rtu_id, meter_id, meter_reading, time_local)
ON (target.rtu_id = source.rtu_id
  AND target.time_local = source.time_local)
WHEN MATCHED
  THEN UPDATE
      SET meter_id = '12B096876'
         ,meter_reading = 56112
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT (rtu_id, meter_id, meter_reading, time_local)
      VALUES (77748, '12B096876', 56112, '20150602 00:20:11');
```

Comment: `'MERGE INTO MyFancyTableName WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target  
   USING 
   (SELECT :id AS id, :lastaccess AS lastaccess ) AS source 
   (id,lastaccess)
   ON 
   (target.id = source.id)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET lastaccess = :lastaccess2
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (id, lastaccess)
   VALUES (:id2, :lastaccess3);'`  Do I need to post both variables in the `USING` select or would just the `id` be sufficient there?

Comment: Thanks for the reference to Merge command. I should point that in the MATCHED STATEMENTS you are using the same values you have defined as source. So if your looking to do a update lot of records you should asigne the source value like this:

Comment: `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET METER_ID = source.RTU_ID,  METER_READING  = source.METER_ID`. Sorry for the double comment, stackoverflow did not let me edit past 6 minutes.

Comment: I tried using MERGE INTO, but got an error that it could not be used on memory-optimized-tables. The tables that are created using CREATE TABLE statement are memory optimized tables by default. I don't know if using WITH (HOLDLOCK) would work. Will try it out. btw..the table in your code - MyBigDB.dbo.METER_DATA is it memory optimized? 
To find if a table is memory optimized, please refer to - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866622/how-to-determine-if-given-table-is-memory-optimized

Answer (score 12):

You can try the other way around. It does the same thing more or less.

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET    field1 = 'Test1', 
       field2 = 'Test2' 
WHERE  id = 1 

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
  INSERT INTO tablename 
              (id, 
               field1, 
               field2) 
  VALUES      (1, 
               'Test1', 
               'Test2')
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server 2008 has this feature, as part of TSQL.
See documentation on MERGE statement here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: Just be aware that MERGE is not immune to high-concurrency insert collision. You must  use WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) for merge to not collide. Some ultra-high-transaction-per-second systems use a different strategy where the locks are not used, but any errors are trapped and then converted to an update.

Answer (score 1):

SQL server 2000 onward has a concept of triggers, which can accomplish the wanted functionality - although there will be a nasty trigger hiding behind the scenes.

Check the section "Insert or update?"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224818(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: Your grammar is confusing. Your phrase "concept of instead of triggers" doesn't contain any useful information.