# SQL Server 2000 equivalent for ON DUPLICATE KEY?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

Is there a SQL Server 2000 functional equivalent to MySQL's ON DUPLICAT KEY clause? [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197733/does-sql-server-offer-anything-like-mysqls-on-duplicate-key-update) led me to look at the Instead of Trigger construct, but the sample looks clunky, and the functionality would be hidden in the trigger, and not be directly in the stored proc.

FWIW: I am trying to create a stats table for per-minute summaries, so that I can just call one Procedure to log the fact that an action happened and increment the counter for the appropriate minute.

Comment: I don't understand why you are assigning an ID if you are looking to disregard the value when a duplicate already exists.  I would omit the ID column from the insert, and just get the @@IDENTITY value if it's necessary.

Comment: OMG: Who said anything about an ID? I'm talking about a key made up of the minute for which the stats are for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does SQL Server Offer Anything Like MySQL's ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197733/does-sql-server-offer-anything-like-mysqls-on-duplicate-key-update)

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```
begin tran;

update ... where ... ;

if @@rowcount = 0
  insert ...
commit tran;
```

As I understand it, with proper indices in place, the update places proper range locks that would prevent others from inserting same thing concurrently.

Comment: Do you need a HoldLock hint on the update to ensure the lock on the index isn't released before the INSERT?

Comment: @Iain you are correct, a holdlock is needed, otherwise it's a RACE issue, where if two transactions are doing the same thing, @@rowcount will be zero and both will insert.

Answer (score 1):

Also clunky, but you could do this in your procedure:

```
insert ... where not exists (...);

update ....;
```

knowing that your insert will fire when the data is new, and your update only when the data exists.

Comment: Is that atomic enough that I could run it from several threads? Should I then insert a 0 count and always call the insert and the update?

Answer (score 0):

**upsert**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsert

```
INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id = ?)
```

**merge**

but i think is only in SQL 2003

```
MERGE INTO table_name USING table_name ON (condition)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET column1 = value1 [, column2 = value2 ...]
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (column1 [, column2 ...]) VALUES (value1 [, value2 ...])
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)

Comment: `MERGE` is SQL Server 2008+ : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: according to wiki its in 2003 (the link that i put in the answer) :
"It was officially introduced in the SQL:2003 standard"

Comment: I can't get the syntax for the upsert example to work in SQL 2000. Should it be able to work there?

Comment: The "SQL 2003 **standard** " is quite a different thing from SQL Server 2008.