# sql statement problem when running multiple executions simultaneously

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

The problem is whenever I execute the stored procedured "**usp_Execute100K**" in  the **Query Windows simultaneously** the server could not locate the record and it creating a new record even though the record is already there. You have to run the "usp_Execute100K" multiple windows  simultaneously to see this problem.

What I want is to make sure the server only create 1 record per day, if the record does exist then only update the "StatisticTotal" column to the next number.

This problem is taught.

The below are 1 table and two stored procedures

Statistic  /*Table name*/

usp_Statistic_InsertOrUpdate  /*this will update the "StatisticTotal" column or insert if the record does not exist*/

usp_Execute100K /* this will execute the  usp_Statistic_InsertOrUpdate  100 thousand times*/

### PLEASE COPY THE SCRIPT BELOW TO RECREATE THE TABLE AND STORED PROCEDURES.

```
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_Execute100K]    Script Date: 09/07/2011 15:37:29 ******/
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Execute100K]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_Statistic_InsertOrUpdate]    Script Date: 09/07/2011 15:37:29 ******/

DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Statistic_InsertOrUpdate]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Statistic]    Script Date: 09/07/2011 15:37:28 ******/
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Statistic]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Statistic]    Script Date: 09/07/2011 15:37:28 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Statistic](
    [StatisticID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [StatisticAccount] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [StatisticTotal] [float] NOT NULL,
    [StatisticCreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DebugDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Statistics] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [StatisticID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_Statistic_InsertOrUpdate]    Script Date: 09/07/2011 15:37:29 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Statistic_InsertOrUpdate](
@StatisticAccount  uniqueidentifier
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT OFF; --this can be turn on or off, it has no effects
DECLARE @NowDate date
SET     @NowDate=CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(char, GETDATE(), 106))--remove all time.
--UPDATE ONLY IF IT HAS THE SAME DATE
UPDATE TOP (1) Statistic SET   StatisticTotal =StatisticTotal+1 WHERE (StatisticAccount=@StatisticAccount AND StatisticCreatedDate = @NowDate)
if @@ROWCOUNT=0--If the above statement return no effects then create a new record
BEGIN
    INSERT TOP (1)INTO Statistic(StatisticID, StatisticAccount, StatisticTotal, StatisticCreatedDate,DebugDate)     VALUES (NEWID(),@StatisticAccount,1,@NowDate,@NowDate)
END
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_Execute100K]    Script Date: 09/07/2011 15:37:29 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Execute100K]
AS
SET NOCOUNT OFF; --this can be turn on or off, it has no effects
declare @current float
set @current=0
while (@current <100000)    
begin
--INSERT THIS STATEMENT for 100 thousand times
    exec usp_Statistic_InsertOrUpdate'4c34eea5-fe17-4b11-8e06-0039577e7421'
    set @current = @current + 1
 end
GO
```

Comment: +1 For providing useful DDL with your question. [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407857/only-inserting-a-row-if-its-not-already-there)

Comment: Should this really be tagged [tag:sql-server-2005]? You're using the `DATE` data type, which is not valid in SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered wrapping your UPDATE/INSERT combo in a transaction? While the constraint and TRY/CATCH will certainly prevent a second row, it will discard the attempt as well. If you wrap it in a transaction, and use TABLOCK (I assume you are potentially doing a lot of writes to this table, but not a ton of reads), you hamper concurrency slightly but you can better ensure that one user will only see the state of the table *after* the other user is done with it. I could get two rows reliably as is, but I couldn't get two rows when I used this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Statistic_InsertOrUpdate]
    @StatisticAccount UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; -- this should always be on

    DECLARE @NowDate DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP; 
    -- by definition, you don't need to convert to remove time from date

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    --UPDATE ONLY IF IT HAS THE SAME DATE
    UPDATE dbo.Statistic WITH (TABLOCK)
      SET StatisticTotal += 1 
      WHERE StatisticAccount = @StatisticAccount 
      AND StatisticCreatedDate = @NowDate;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
    -- If the above statement return no effects then create a new record
    BEGIN
        INSERT dbo.Statistic
        (
          StatisticID,
          StatisticAccount,
          StatisticTotal,
          StatisticCreatedDate,
          DebugDate
        )
        SELECT
          NEWID(),
          @StatisticAccount,
          1,
          @NowDate,
          @NowDate;
    END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
GO
```

Error trapping, rollback, constraints etc. I'll leave as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

1) create a unique index on `Statistic.StatisticAccount + Statistic.StatisticCreatedDate` or just `Statistic.StatisticCreatedDate` what ever your business rules dictate.

2) wrap your INSERT WITH:

```
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT ...
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

it will just ignore/throw away the error generated by the failed duplicate insert.