# Checking if record exist and exiting in most effective way

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have following script inside my stored procedure

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.MBLPosition WHERE PositionGKey = @i_PositionGKey) RETURN

-- DO SOME STUFF HERE

INSERT dbo.MBLPosition..
```

I'm inserting some data into table (single record). First I check if it exist already, then I do some processing and insert record.

Processing can take some time - let's say 2 seconds. Some times calls come in subsequently and I get constraint exceptions. Rare, but happens. I want to avoid this and at the same time I don't want to do this processing if record already exist. What is the best way to structure this code so I don't do extra work and avoid exception?

This is large table with records coming in all the time. What is the best way to filter out dupes as they come in and don't spend much processing time?

Comment: You might want to use [merge](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx), and do `when not matched` part only. This would be test and insert at once.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Only inserting a row if it's not already there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407857/only-inserting-a-row-if-its-not-already-there)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to perform the check and then you can always use try/catch to attempt the insert. As @MitchWheat pointed out you can eliminate this using proper transaction handling.

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.MBLPosition 
  WHERE PositionGKey = @i_PositionGKey
)
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY
    -- do some stuff here
    INSERT dbo.MBLPosition..
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH 
    PRINT 'Not an exception, but insert failed';
  END CATCH
END
```

I treated a similar topic here:

- [Checking for potential constraint violations before entering TRY and CATCH logic](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2632/checking-for-potential-constraint-violations-before-entering-sql-server-try-and-catch-logic/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

Comment: Thank you, your article helped me to make decision. Percent of duplicates is very small in my case so I can even benefit from using TRY CATCH.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a [transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (of sufficient isolation level) to make the test and subsequent `INSERT` atomic.

You might possibly want to turn on Snapshot Isolation if you then encounter deadlocks (as you say processing may take some time, although 2 seconds seems quite long....)

Comment: Can you elaborate on proper transaction handling?