# Using Case statement to either Insert into a table or Update an existing row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, insert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Solutions for INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server)
>   [Only inserting a row if it's not already there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407857/only-inserting-a-row-if-its-not-already-there)

My title pretty much explains what I'm trying to do, but I'll go into a little more detail. I'm creating a stored procedure when called it first checks to see if the row already exists (by comparing against two parameters) and if it does, it will update a specific column in the row and if the row doesn't exist already it will insert a new row into the table.

```
BEGIN
SELECT 
(
CASE WHEN [Site] = @site and Plant = @plant
then 
UPDATE [Status]
FROM Server_Status
WHERE [Site] = @site
ELSE
Insert into Server_Status(Name, [Path], [Site], Plant, [Status])
Values (@name, @path, @site, @plant, @status)
end
)
FROM Server_Status 
END
```

Is what I have so far, but doesn't work (obviously). Does anyone with more SQL knowledge than I have any suggestions?

-J

Comment: [Case is not a control-of-flow method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) What version of SQL Server?

Comment: You will also need to fix your `UPDATE` statement needs to be in the form of `UPDATE MyTable SET MyField=...`

Comment: SQL Server 2008/ SSMS, Thanks for the other threads to look at too Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to take ta look at the [MERGE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement.

> Performs insert, update, or delete operations on a target table based
>   on the results of a join with a source table. For example, you can
>   synchronize two tables by inserting, updating, or deleting rows in one
>   table based on differences found in the other table.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE...)
 --value exists perform update
  BEGIN
    UPDATE...
  END
ELSE
  --value doesnt exist perform insert
  BEGIN
    INSERT ...
  END
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first check for the existence of the row using the IF EXISTS statement as follows:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Server_Status WHERE Site = @Site) 
BEGIN
    -- UPDATE statement.
END
ELSE
    -- INSERT statement.
END
```

Comment: The update statement is not formed correctly.  What are you updating?

Comment: I just copied from his SELECT :). The idea was to drive the IF EXISTS statement usage.