# IF NOT EXISTS doesn't appear to be working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following script:

```
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT SessionID FROM SessionData WHERE SessionID = @SessionID)
    BEGIN
    SELECT @RegionID = RegionID
    FROM Region
    WHERE Domain = @Domain
    INSERT INTO SessionData (
    SessionID,
    SystemID,
    RegionID,
    RegionDomain,
    RemoteAddr,
    CreatePage)
    VALUES (
    @SessionID,
    @SystemID,
    @RegionID,
    @RegionDomain,
    @RemoteAddr,
    @CreatePage)
END
END
```

Occasionally the site produces an error as follows:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_SessionData'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'sbuser.SessionData'.  The duiplicate key
>   value is (1h6l61h069srw1nmw73j). Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for
>   SQL Server Number: -2147217873

Why does it run the script, if there is a duplicate key..?  I am confused..  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks..

Comment: Not sure why you get that error, but I'd recommend using the "MERGE" statement for this work, as it performs check/update it in one pass.

Comment: What happens if you make ` ... WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT ...)` part of the insert statement rather than a conditional branch?

Comment: @Tim - [That won't prevent the race condition without additional locking hints](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3407857/73226)

Comment: put the whole thing inside a transaction.

Answer (score 4):

Two concurrent overlapping processes will both pass the NOT EXISTS check and try to INSERT.

That is, the NOT EXISTS is a separate query to the INSERT

Both the NOT EXISTS and the INSERT can be written into a single MERGE

```
MERGE INTO
    SessionData WITH (SERIALIZABLE) S
USING (
    SELECT
        @SessionID AS SessionID ,
        @SystemID AS SystemID ,
        RegionID,
        @RegionDomain AS RegionDomain ,
        @RemoteAddr AS RemoteAddr ,
        @CreatePage AS CreatePage 
    FROM Region
    WHERE Domain = @Domain
    ) src ON S.SessionID = src.SessionID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (
       SessionID,
       SystemID,
       RegionID,
       RegionDomain,
       RemoteAddr,
       CreatePage)
    VALUES (
       src.SessionID,
       src.SystemID,
       src.RegionID,
       src.RegionDomain,
       src.RemoteAddr,
       src.CreatePage);
```

Comment: could you explain this further..?  How would I rewrite the script to avoid this issue?

Comment: @openshac: I don't need one with MERGE: this is the point of MERGE to do a single call and remove the need for one

Comment: I know you don't need one with MERGE :-) I was responding to @neojakey who asked if he could rewrite the script.

Comment: @gbn - If I was to remove SELECT RegionID FROM Region WHERE Domain = Domain from the script and got the regionid before I ran this script.. would that solve the problem..?

Comment: @neojakey: no. The problem is the NOT EXISTS..INSERT. Use Merge like I said

Comment: It appears that this query will fail to insert anything if a matching row is not found in the Region table. I doubt that's the desired behavior.

Comment: @JLRishe: This was based on OPs select. Given we don't have the table definition and can see if it allows NULLs, either of us could be right.

Comment: OP's query has concurrency issues, but it does not have the issue I am describing. It's not a matter of whether the SessionData table allows NULLs. If there is no matching row in the Region table, then `SELECT ... FROM Region WHERE Domain = @Domain` will produce 0 rows, meaning that `src` will have 0 rows, and there will be nothing to insert.

Comment: If SessionData.RegionID is NOT NULL then a row *must* exist on the Region table. As it stands, I'm fixing concurrency based on incomplete information..

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
INSERT INTO SessionData (
   SessionID,
   SystemID,
   RegionID,
   RegionDomain,
   RemoteAddr,
   CreatePage)
SELECT
   @SessionID,
   @SystemID,
   (SELECT TOP 1 RegionID FROM Region WHERE Domain = @Domain),
   @RegionDomain,
   @RemoteAddr,
   @CreatePage)
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT SessionID FROM SessionData WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) 
                                WHERE SessionID = @SessionID)
```

That's a concise way to get an atomic operation without any MERGEs or transactions.

Comment: -1: still not safe for concurrency. The NOT EXISTs can still give true. Why I use MERGE with SERIALIZABLE... See my answers here http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a27535%20jfdi

Comment: You can ofc use locking hints as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/3407890/27535 (see comments) to make it safe. But your code is what MERGE does internally anyway... Also see http://michaeljswart.com/2011/09/mythbusting-concurrent-updateinsert-solutions/