# SQL number generation in concurrent environment (Transation isolation level)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I am working with an application that generates invoice numbers (sequentially based on few parameters) and so far it has been using a trigger with serialized transaction. Because the trigger is rather "heavy" it manages to timeout execution of the insert query.

I'm now working on a solution to that problem and so far I came to the point where I have a stored procedure that do the insert and after the insert I have a transaction with isolation level serializable (which by the way applies to that transaction only or should i set it back after the transaction has been commited?) that:

- gets the number
- if not found do the insert into that table and if found updates the number (increment)
- commits the transaction

I'm wondering whether there's a better way to ensure the number is used once and gets incrementer with the table locked (only the number tables gets locked, right?).

I read about sp_getapplock, would that be somewhat a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: I think without seeing where the problem occurs in your code, the best you're going to get is a shot in the dark.

Comment: If there's only one source of sequential numbers, use the identity column. If there is more than one source and your stored procedure picks the correct one each time, use [sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091%28v=sql.120%29.aspx).

Comment: @GSerg that seems interesting, I'm not a DB guy and I didn't know about sequences at all. There's one more thing I need from that solution - I must be able to easily modify the number of the next sequential number. Will I be able to do that with sequences?

Comment: @GSerg I cannot use sequences, I must leave it SQL Server 2008 compatible.

Comment: @user1970395 It is very unclear what your setup even is. How do you calculate numbers, where and why do you store them?

Comment: @GSerg Alright, I'm using a table "numbers" that stores year, month, office, type and obviously next number - based on those 4 parameters I need to get this number, then I increment it (only for a row where those 4 parameters matched), then I create a real alphanumeric invoice number based on this sequence number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would optimize the routine for update (and handle "[insert if not there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3407857/11683)" separately), at which point it would be:

```
declare @number int;

update tbl
set @number = number, number += 1
where year = @year and month = @month and office = @office and type = @type;
```

You don't need any specific locking hints or isolation levels, SQL Server will ensure no two transactions read the same value before incrementing.

---

If you'd like to avoid handling the insert separately, you can:

```
merge into tbl
using (values (@year, @month, @office, @type)) as v(y,m,o,t)
on tbl.year = v.year and tbl.month = v.month and tbl.office = v.office and tbl.type = v.type
when not matched by target then
  insert (year, month, office, type, number) values(@year, @month, @office, @type, 1)
when matched then
  update set @number = tbl.number, tbl.number += 1
;
```

Logically this should provide the same guard against race condition as `update`, but for some reason I don't remember where is the proof.

Comment: Thank You @GSerg, I beleive that should solve the issue, despite the one I described in my question works as expected with no problems and deadlocks (or timeouts), your first solution seems way clearer! Are You sure it does not require transaction? ;> Because it's being used inside SP which is a batch, not a transaction (unless .NET wraps it into transaction in background which I'm not sure)

Comment: This particular query does not need a transaction for the purpose of avoiding two clients generating same id. For anything else you certainly should use a transaction whenever you have more than one statement that are supposed to work together.

Answer (score 0):

If you first insert and then update you have a time window where an invalid number is set and can be observed. Further, if the 2nd transaction fails which can always happen you have inconsistent data.

Try this:

1. Take a fresh number in tran 1.
2. Insert in tran 2 with the number that was taken already

That way you might burn a number but there will never be inconsistent data.

Comment: If you insert and update in the same transaction, only those who are happy with dirty reads might see it, otherwise there is no time window for the invalid number.

Comment: @GSerg I agree, also the drawback of proposed solution is that I must ensure insert will happen otherwise I may have a gap and by the financial law of any country I believe there must be no gaps in invoice numbers.

Comment: @usr and I also don't mind that invalid number may be observerd, the insert and the rest executes in about 30 ms so the time window is rather no-time.

Comment: @user1970395 did I understand you right that you are using two transactions right now? Then you have potential data inconsistency. Can't do that if inconsistency is not allowed.