# Perform a get-row-if-exists-otherwise-create query

Tags: sql-server, race-condition

I'm working within a microservice environment and have two independent Azure serverless functions that both perform a SQL `INSERT` if a prior `SELECT` returns no row. Each serverless function runs on an as-needed basis based on various triggers. At times, the functions can be running at the exact same time which appears to be exposing a race condition. The race condition being that both functions will first check if a row exists in a table and if it does not exist it will create it, but if both functions do this at the same time then the both see that no record exists and one creates it while the otherwise fails due to a unique key constraint in the database table.

What approaches are there for me to remove this race condition?

Is there a solution that I can perform purely in SQL (a query, locking, stored procedure, etc) that would allow me to leverage that solution in my code without having to go with a larger code modification to fix the issue?

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3407890/1127428) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a solution that I can perform purely in SQL

Yes.  In a transaction, check for the row with the (UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK) query hints.

eg

```
begin transaction

if not exists (
  select *
  from sometable with (updlock,holdlock)
  where Name = @SomeName
)
begin
  insert into sometable(...)   
end

commit transaction
```

This will lock the target row (or empty range) so if two sessions run this at the same time, one will be blocked on SELECT until the other commits the insert.

Comment: Is there an advantage to using 'if not exists' rather than `where not exists`?

Comment: @DaleK `WHERE NOT EXISTS` will still fire triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you mean is that you want to actually see the result of that row:

You can actually do this in a single statement using `MERGE`.

```sql
DECLARE @found bit;

MERGE sometable WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) AS t
USING (VALUES (@Id, @SomeValue) ) AS v(Id, SomeValue)
  ON t.Id = v.Id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (Id, SomeValue)
  VALUES (v.Id, v.SomeValue)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
  SET @found = 1
OUTPUT inserted.*;
```

But given that `MERGE` is known to have bugs, I would still advise a separate `IF NOT EXISTS ... INSERT` and `SELECT` pairs.

Comment: Does the `where not exists` solution not solve this problem?

Comment: I've assumed OP actually wants the row sent back to the client.