# Possible to simulate the mySQL functionality ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, concurrency, merge

I am using SQL Server 2008, and would like to be able to take advantage of something like mySQL's ON `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause for `INSERT` statements

Current legacy code does a delete and subsequent insert that is running into concurrency issues with duplicate key inserts from separate threads:

Here is the error I see in my production environment:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Audience'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Audience'.
```

(sp_ContentUpdate)

Primary Key:

```
AudienceId, VersionId
```

Offending SQL:

```
DELETE  FROM  dbo.Audience
WHERE   VersionId = @VersionId

IF  @AudienceXml IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Audience (
        VersionId,
        AudienceId,
        CreatedDate,
        CreatedByPersonId,
        )
    SELECT  @VersionId,
            AudienceId,
            GETUTCDATE(),
            @PersonId
                FROM    dbo.Audience
    JOIN    @AudienceXml.nodes('/Audiences/Audience') node(c)
    ON      Audience.AudienceName = c.value('@Name', 'nvarchar(50)')
    END
```

Wrapping this TSQL in a transaction seems to either remove the concurrency issue or mask the issue by changing the timings.  However, I do not think wrapping in a transaction has actually solved the concurrency.

Perhaps I am going about this wrong.  Your suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does SQL Server Offer Anything Like MySQL's ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197733/does-sql-server-offer-anything-like-mysqls-on-duplicate-key-update)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, Bill beat us all, but here's a sample of what it might look like:

```
Merge dbo.Audience As target
Using   (
        Select @VersionId As VersionId, AudienceId, GetUtcDate() As CreatedDate, @PersonId As CreatedByPersonId
        From dbo.Audience
            Join @AudienceXml.nodes('/Audiences/Audience') node(c)
                On Audience.AudienceName = c.value('@Name', 'nvarchar(50)')
        )
When Matched Then
    Update 
    Set VersoinId = target.VersionId, Audience = target.AudienceId
        , CreatedDate = target.CreatedDate
        , CreatedByPersionId = target.CreatedByPersonId
When Not Matched Then
    Insert dbo.Audience(VersionId, AudienceId, CreatedDate, CreatedByPersonId)
```

Comment: @Bill Karwin - Thx. When you answered, I felt like Rusty's character when he tries to recruit Saul in Ocean's 11. "Thomas, I saw the answer before you got up this morning." But, the brownie points for a bit of extra work is nice too. :)

Comment: Aren't you missing an "on" clause to couple the target and source tables?

Answer (score 8):

You should read about how to use the `MERGE` statement in Microsoft SQL Server 2008.  This is actually the ANSI/ISO SQL way of handling this situation (MySQL's ON DUPLICATE KEY is a proprietary MySQLism).

See docs on the [`MERGE` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) at MSDN.