# SQL Server insert statement to auto increment

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL insert statement like the following:

```
insert into mytable(ID,Keyindex,KeyValue) 
select Id,1,GenreID 
from mytable2
```

Which should populate my table with data like:

```
id                                      GenreID  ColumnB
0006342c-47bc-436a-a23a-3b40360d9a30    16       1
0006342c-47bc-436a-a23a-3b40360d9a30    19       1
00109775-f0f8-463e-8134-f842aac8b5df    12       1
001211e3-9bf8-45ad-8297-7a0a94aaf06e    13       1
0025218a-9624-4f5e-86cc-f1cfe862cd2a    16       1 
0025218a-9624-4f5e-86cc-f1cfe862cd2a    11       1
0025218a-9624-4f5e-86cc-f1cfe862cd2a    15       1
```

The problem is ID,GenreId and ColumnB  are primary keys and I am currently inserting a constand value "1"  which results in a primary key violation.

How do I insert into the table so that ColumnB gets populated with a value incrementaly if the IDs are the same.

For example:

```
id                                      GenreID  ColumnB
0006342c-47bc-436a-a23a-3b40360d9a30    16       1 
0006342c-47bc-436a-a23a-3b40360d9a30    19       2 
00109775-f0f8-463e-8134-f842aac8b5df    12       1
001211e3-9bf8-45ad-8297-7a0a94aaf06e    13       1
0025218a-9624-4f5e-86cc-f1cfe862cd2a    16       1
0025218a-9624-4f5e-86cc-f1cfe862cd2a    16       2
0025218a-9624-4f5e-86cc-f1cfe862cd2a    16       3
```

Comment: The column names in your first part are out of synch with those shown in the second part.

Comment: So you just want ColumnB to increment if the combination of GenreID and ColumnB will not be unique? Sounds like you'll need a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little confusing.  In the "for example" section it looks like the genreID for `0025218a-9624-4f5e-86cc-f1cfe862cd2a` should be `16,17,19` instead of `16,16,16`.

Assuming I understand you correct, though, you can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` partitioned by the id.  Something like the following should work :

```
insert into mytable(ID,Keyindex,KeyValue) 
select   id, GenreID , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by id order by id) as ColumnB
from     mytable2
order by id, 
         genereid
```

Note: you didn't specify version, but this will work in sql 2005+

Answer (score 0):

A dirty hack would be to use `id - someNumber` or `id + someNumber` instead of just `1`.

What can be accepted if this is a "fire and forget" one time operation.

If you have to check the uniqueness, then a trigger can be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the ON DUPLICATE option:

```
insert into mytable(ID,Keyindex,KeyValue) 
select Id,1,GenreID 
from mytable2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Keyindex = Keyindex+1;
```

Comment: Note this is untested. Just a quick thought. Modify as needed.

Comment: If you're not using MySQL, check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197733/does-sql-server-offer-anything-like-mysqls-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

Comment: The ON DUPLICATE syntax won't work for SQL server.  You'll need a BEFORE INSERT trigger.