# Remove column redundancy by increment

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sqlite

I have the following table :

[image]

As you can see I have duplicated date and time values like 2012-01-01 09:29:00.000 and 2012-01-01 09:29:00.008.

I need your help to remove the redundancy by adding milliseconds to duplicated hours and obtain the following result :

[image]

So I created a table TableSource and I tried to insert the new outputs values ​​without redondonce but I have not succeeded.

I think the following query can solve the problem but it work only on My-sql :

```
INSERT INTO TableDestination
SELECT * FROM TableSource
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE  NeededDateRow = DATEADD(millisecond,1 , NeededDateRow)
```

Comment: Do you want a specific number of milliseconds added to the duplicated datetimes? Or could it be a random number? (And out of curiosity: why do you want no duplicate datetimes in your column?)

Comment: I just need to add milliseconds to differentiate dates ca can be random. I dont want duplicate values because i use it in an oder query as primary key and this causes a problem in the dates duplicated. thx.

Comment: @Tlachtga Check my answer below, it should help you solve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
    DECLARE @table table (id int, dt datetime)
DECLARE @table2 table (id int, dt datetime)
INSERT INTO @table 
SELECT 1, '2012/01/01'
UNION
SELECT 2, '2012/01/01'
UNION
SELECT 3, '2012/01/01'
UNION
SELECT 1, '2012/01/02'

SELECT * , DATEADD(millisecond, 10 * (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dt ORDER BY dt) - 1), dt) As NewDate
FROM @table 

INSERT INTO @table2
SELECT ID, DATEADD(millisecond, 10 * (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dt ORDER BY dt) - 1)  , dt) FROM @table 

SELECT * from @table2
```

Comment: thx for your answer, the select query seems work but when i try to update i get the following error: Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

Comment: check my updated answer, you can insert using select and it will insert date column with correct order into TableDestination.

Comment: It works great thank you Lots! I will preferre your first solution by updating the same table, it is not possible to do?

Comment: Sorry i think not, you cannot use row_number in update directly.

Comment: Ok no problem thx, i will use delete from table1 and insert into table1 select * from table2

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE` KEY in MSSQL, However , 
**MERGE** and **WHEN NOT MATCHED** might be work for you.

you can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197733/does-sql-server-offer-anything-like-mysqls-on-duplicate-key-update)

and I just draft the sql syntax (untested)

```
MERGE TableDestination AS T
USING TableSource AS S
ON (T.NeededDateRow = S.NeededDateRow)
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT (NeededDateRow) VALUES (DateAdd(millisecond,1,NeededDateRow))
```

Comment: thx  but i have already see that answer, and the merge query havn't work for me because in my case i need to use WHEN MACHED THEN INSERT (NeededDateRow) VALUES (DateAdd(millisecond,1,NeededDateRow) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN INSERT (NeededDateRow) and the insert not work with WHEN MATCHED.