# Derby JavaDB Query ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: java, mysql, derby, javadb

I know that `MySQL` supports this query (`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`) for example:

```
INSERT INTO UserFailure (Realm, Username, DateOfFailure, CountOfFailure) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE CountOfFailure=?;
```

When I am running this on embedded `Derby DB` it gives me:

```
PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO UserFailure (Realm, Username, DateOfFailure, CountOfFailure) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE CountOfFailure=?;]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "ON" at line 1, column 91.
```

I assume that `Derby` does not support this feature.

Is there a query I can use to update the database record on duplicate key from `Derby` and from `MySQL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch the duplicate key exception yourself, and issue the update.

Comment: Yes I know I can do that, but aren't there any query that will do the same in Derby and MySql?

Comment: MySQL's SQL language extensions are generally not implemented by other databases. See this related question for some more ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197733/does-sql-server-offer-anything-like-mysqls-on-duplicate-key-update