# C# (ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE) Error

Tags: c#, sql-server

This are my SQL columns:
**ItemID, ItemName, Unit, Quantity, UnitCost, Total, Status**

ItemID is my *barcode number* and primary key. Quantity is an integer and has an identity increment value of 1.

If you call the same sql query twice, it doesn't allow you to duplicate a primary key.

**What I want:** If the query was called twice, then increase the Quantity value by 1, and double the UnitCost value, to be placed in the Total section.

My idea was that if it was a duplicate key, then just update it.

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET
```

but I'm getting errors all over the place.

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO Grocery (ItemID, ItemName, Unit, UnitCost, Total, Status) VALUES ('2414', '2414', 'EACH', '1.5', '1.5', 'LP') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ItemName='changed'"; 
connection.Open();
        SqlCeCommand commandInsert = new SqlCeCommand(sql, connection);
                    commandInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: this question is duplicate please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197733/does-sql-server-offer-anything-like-mysqls-on-duplicate-key-update

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to update the values in a table by inserting it.

You have to,

> First set the `Quantity` is normal `integer` column
>
> Then check the given item already exists in the table.
>
> - If exists, then update the `Quantity` and `Total` columns
> - Else insert the item into the table

Hope this helps.

Comment: Or use the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` or merge for sql-server

Comment: But why we need quantity as identity column?

Comment: Besides identity, On duplicate key doesn't work for me. Gives me an error. Does the query string have to be multi line formatted?

Comment: @Machina possible post your table schema here.

Comment: I believe On Duplicate Key Update is for MySql. It looks like you are using Sql Server Ce, which doesn't support the MERGE statement mentioned already. In this case you must use insert/update to handle it, and determine if the record exists first to determine your branching action.