# SQL query for insert into with update on duplicate key is error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got error on the following query

```
INSERT INTO tableName3 (column1, column2)
    SELECT 
        b.column1,
        SUM (a.column2) AS SumColumn2
    FROM 
        tableName1 AS a
    JOIN 
        tableName2 AS b ON a.column1 = b.column2 
    GROUP BY 
        b.column2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tableName3
   SET column2 = SUM (a.column2) AS SumColumn2
```

The error messages are

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON*'

and

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

How to fix it?

Comment: what is the key of `tableName3`?

Comment: how about sql server?

Comment: the key of tableName3 is coloumn1

Comment: sorry the above query is not for oracle but sql server

Comment: [It's still a duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1197733/266304).

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks I'll record the information for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First,** your select statement is wrong.

```
SELECT 
    b.column1,
    SUM (a.column2) AS SumColumn2
FROM 
    tableName1 AS a
JOIN 
    tableName2 AS b ON a.column1 = b.column2 
GROUP BY 
    b.column2
```

this should probably be grouped by `b.column1`, otherwise you will get an exception since columns in the select clause must appear either in the group by clause or in an aggregating function in [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server)

**Second**, there is no `ON DUPLICATE KEY` directive in Sql server. A Quick search found many references for this in [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), but [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) is **not** [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server).

To achieve this kind of behavior in Sql server you should probably use [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement.

Your code should look something like this:

```
MERGE tableName3  AS target
USING (
    SELECT 
    b.column1,
    SUM (a.column2) AS SumColumn2
    FROM 
    tableName1 AS a
    JOIN 
    tableName2 AS b ON a.column1 = b.column2 
    GROUP BY 
    b.column1
) AS source (column1, SumColumn2)
ON (target.column1= source.column1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET column2= source.SumColumn2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (column1, column2)
    VALUES (source.column1, source.SumColumn2)
```