# SQL query insert and update on duplicate key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have aTable. aTable has the following records:

```
    +----+------+------------------+--------+
    | No | Name | Date(mm/dd/yyyy) | Salary | 
    +----+------+------------------+--------+
    | 1  | Ed   |    04/01/2016    | 1000   |
    | 2  | Tom  |    04/02/2016    | 1500   |
    +----+------+------------------+--------+
```

How about the SQL Server query to produce these results to other table:

```
+----+------+------------------+--------+---+
| No | Name | Date(yyyy/mm/dd) | Salary | k |
+----+------+------------------+--------+---+
| 1  | Ed   |    04/01/2016    | 1000   | 0 |
| 2  | Tom  |    04/02/2016    | 1500   | 0 |
+----+------+------------------+--------+---+
```

and update when duplicate key. The primary key is No and Name

Comment: Why a two column pk? Isn't no enough (i.e. distinct)?

Comment: why not use the merge statement as I've shown you in a [previous question?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36678294/3094533)

Answer (score 1):

You want to produce exactly the same data as your table in a new table only with a new column k which is "0" in any case?

```
SELECT *,0 AS k
INTO TheNewTable
FROM YourTable;
```

Then try it out with

```
SELECT * FROM TheNewTable;
```

But - to be honest - this seems quite strange...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Insert into second_table_name(No, Name, Date, Salary, k) 
    select 
        No, Name, Date, Salary, 0 
    from aTable
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary key is UNIQUE so you can't duplicate it. Or maybe your logical key is other combination for example Name, Date, Salary then example query could be like this:

```
MERGE aNewTable as Target
USING 
(
    SELECT Name, Date, Salary, CASE WHEN Count(*) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as K
    FROM aTable
    GROUP BY Name, Date, Salary
) as Source ON Source.Name=Target.Name AND Source.Date=Target.Date AND Source.Salary=Target.Salary
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Name, Date, Salary, K)
    VALUES (Source.Name, Source.Date, Source.Salary, Source.K)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
    SET K = Source.K
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE;
```

or simple to view:

```
SELECT Name, Date, Salary, CASE WHEN Count(*) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as K
FROM aTable
GROUP BY Name, Date, Salary
```