# Update and insert to one table from another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two tables:

`table1`: (ID, Code, Name)
`table2`: (ID, Code, Name)
with same columns

I want to to insert data from table1 to table2 or update columns if that exists in table2  (table1.ID = table2.ID)

What is the simple way to do this?

WITH OUT **MERGE**

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197733/does-sql-server-offer-anything-like-mysqls-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: You merge table 1 into table 2, update where matched and insert where not - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: I cant use Merge because my database is SQL SERVER 2005

Comment: Then you may have to do it in two steps: 1) Insert missing rows from `table2` into `table1`, 2) update rows that don't match. As a side note, is there any particular reason you need two identical tables?

Comment: yes, Im inserting and updating into table1 many times then I need to do that operations at once to table2

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a solution that will allow you to insert and update in a single operation in SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Merge table2 as target
using table1  as source
on
target.id=source.id
When matched 
Then
update 
set target.id=source.id,
    target.name=source.name
When not matched by Target Then
INSERT (id, name) VALUES (id, name);
```

There are some issues with Merge statement,so it should be used with [caution](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)..

Further i recommend ,using merge as two seperate DML statements like below..

```
insert into table2
select * from table1 t1 where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id=t1.id)

update t2
set 
t2.id=t1.id,
t2.name=t1.name
from 
table1 t1
join
table2 t2
on t1.id=t2.id
```

Reasons being stated by [Paul White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440595/paul-white) here in his detailed [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30633/merge-a-subset-of-the-target-table)..

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.Any obvious reasons.. or pointers..?

Comment: it is obvious reason. if you insert first then you update freshly inserted records as well ;)

Comment: I would agree.  Use update first.  Also, I would wrap the insert/update (2 statements) in a TRANS.

Answer (score 1):

```
MERGE table2 t2
USING table1 t1
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET t2.Code = t1.Code, t2.Name = t1.Name 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (ID, Name, Code)
  VALUES (t1.ID, t1.Name, t1.Code);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ID column is unique and should not be set, it seems you could do it in two SQL Statements.

```
/* UPDATE the rows in TABLE2 */
UPDATE TABLE2
    SET NAME = (SELECT NAME FROM TABLE1 WHERE TABLE1.CODE = TABLE2.CODE)
WHERE CODE IN (SELECT CODE FROM TABLE1)

/* INSERT the rows that are missing */
INSERT INTO TABLE2
    (CODE, NAME)
    (
         SELECT CODE, NAME
         FROM TABLE1
         WHERE CODE NOT IN (SELECT CODE FROM TABLE2)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

get all rows that are in table1 but not in table2

```
insert into table2(id, code, name)(
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id)
WHERE table2.C IS NULL
)
```

update table2

```
update table2 set name = (select name from table1 where table1.code = table2.code and table1.id = table2.id)
```

It might be worth looking at [triggers](http://[http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25600/Triggers-SQL-Server]) on update and insert if you'd like to have this done manually

Answer (score 0):

Inserting Date into **target table** once date is updated in **source table**
Here there is a working example:

```
create table Table1(id int,name varchar(100));
create table Table2(id int,name varchar(100));
create trigger Table1Trigger after insert on Table1 for each row begin
    insert into Table2(id, name) values (new.id, new.name);
end;
```

Use the following queries to validate the results

```
insert into Table1 values(1,'John'),(2,'Smith'),(3,'Carol');
```

Answer (score -1):

Here I am writing a script that use full when you want to update table2 from table1.

```
    Update table2 set table2.code = table1.code, table2.name=table1.name from table1 where table2.id=table1.id
```

And if you want to insert then use this script.

```
Insert into table2  (id,code,name) select id,code,name from table1
```

If in table2 id is not auto increment.
Otherwise not insert the value of id column in table2.