# Insert or Update Data into Table with Foreign Key from Another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have two tables

```
Table VendorMaster
|VendorID|Vendor|
|    1   |Vendor1|
|    2   |Vendor2|

Table Data
|DataID|VendorID|ProductName|Quantity|
|   1  |    1   |  Product1 |   100  |
|   2  |    1   |  Product2 |   200  |
|   3  |    2   |  Product1 |   400  |
|   4  |    2   |  Product2 |   100  |
```

A vendor can have multiple products which are referred using foreign key
Now I have another table used for staging the data

```
Table Staging
|StagingID|Vendor|ProductName|Quantity|
```

I need to insert or update the data into the Data table and Vendor table from the Staging table. Like the staging table can be used to update only the quantities or add new vendor and / or product.

How do I proceed with it? I am using SQL Server.

I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189485/update-and-insert-to-one-table-from-another), but it cannot update / insert the foreign key master table.

Comment: need more information to see what problem you are facing and how you map `staging` table with `data`and `vendor`table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write below code to insert & update respective tables and I am assuming that VendorID & DataID columns are identity columns.

```
insert into VendorMaster (Vendor)
select Vendor
from Staging s
where not exists (
select 1 from  VendorMaster v 
where v.vendor = s.vendor
);


Update d
set Quantitty = s.Quantity
from Data d
inner join venderMaster v on d.vendorid = v.vendorid
inner join staging s on s.vendor = v.vendor 
and s.productName = d.productname
and d.Quantity <> s.Quantity;

insert into Data (VendorID,ProductName,Quantity)
select VendorID,ProductName,Quatity
from Vendor v
inner join staging s on s.Vendor = v.Vendor 
where not exists
(
 select 1 from Data d 
where d.vendorid = v.vendorid
and s.productName = d.productname
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in 2 steps in this particular order:

1. Keep the `VendorMaster` table up to date with new vendors. I'm assuming that the vendor name is your key here (it shouldn't be the name though, what happens if you have 2 different vendors with same name?) and `VendorID` is an `IDENTITY`.

   ```
   INSERT INTO VendorMaster (
       Vendor)
   SELECT DISTINCT
       S.Vendor
   FROM
       Staging AS S
   WHERE
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'vendor not yet loaded' FROM VendorMaster AS V
                   WHERE V.Vendor = S.Vendor)
   ```
2. Update (if exists) & Insert (if not exists) the data from each vendor. I'm assuming the key on this table will be `VendorID` and `ProductName` (it shouldn't be product name, it should be `ProductID`, or the such), and that `DataID` is `IDENTITY`. The operations must be in this particular order to prevent pointless updating. The update won't update if it doesn't exist and the insert won't insert if it already exist:

   ```
   UPDATE D SET
       Quantity = S.Quantity
   FROM
       Staging AS S
       INNER JOIN VendorMaster AS V ON S.Vendor = V.Vendor -- Fetch the VendorID from VendorMaster
       INNER JOIN Data AS D ON
           V.VendorID = D.VendorID AND
           S.ProductName = D.ProductName
   WHERE
       S.Quantity <> D.Quantity -- Update only if there are differences

   INSERT INTO Data (
       VendorID,
       ProductName,
       Quantity)
   SELECT
       VendorID = V.VendorID,
       ProductName = S.ProductName,
       Quantity = S.Quantity
   FROM
       Staging AS S
       INNER JOIN VendorMaster AS V ON S.Vendor = V.Vendor -- Fetch the VendorID from VendorMaster
   WHERE
       NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT
               'data not yet loaded'
           FROM
               Data AS D
           WHERE
               V.VendorID = D.VendorID AND
               S.ProductName = D.ProductName)
   ```