# JdbcBatchItemWriter - Incorrect Syntax near the Keyword 'ON'

Tags: java, sql-server, spring

I'm running the following query to insert a record into my SQL Server database from my Spring application using [JdbcBatchItemWriter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcBatchItemWriter.html)

```
"INSERT INTO USER (username, address) VALUES (:username,:address) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username = username"
```

But am getting the following exception

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{my_query_above}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.
```

The query runs fine without the `ON` condition. Any idea why this is failing?

UPDATE

here's the write config

```
@Bean
public ItemWriter<User> userWriter(DataSource dataSource) throws SQLException {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<User> userWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<User>();
    userWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<StagingProcess>());
    userWriter.setSql(QueryUtil.QUERY_INSERT_PROCESS);
    userWriter.setDataSource(sqlServerDataSource());
    return userWriter;
}

@Primary
@Bean(name="sqlserverDS")
public static DataSource sqlServerDataSource() throws SQLException {
    final DriverManagerDataSource sqlServerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();      sqlServerDataSource.setDriverClassName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
    sqlServerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://myHost:8080/myDB");
    sqlServerDataSource.setUsername("user");
    sqlServerDataSource.setPassword("password");
    return sqlServerDataSource;
}
```

More of the stacktrace

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{my_query_above}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.    
     at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:662) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:950) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.executeBatchUpdateWithNamedParameters(NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.java:40) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:335) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter.write(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:181) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:175) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:151) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:274) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:199) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_101]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_101]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_101]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_101]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) [spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) [spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
```

Comment: `JdbcTemplate` doesn't support named parameters,use wildcards instead.

Comment: Sorry Deinum, had to rephrase my question - I'm using JdbcBatchItemWriter for this query

Comment: Then post some configuration and please add the full stacktrace instead of a small snippet.

Comment: Also make sure you are actually using a MySQL version that supports that syntax.

Comment: Included config and stacktrace thank you

Comment: You are using MySQL syntax on a MSSqlServer... MySQL <> MSSQLServer... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197733/does-sql-server-offer-anything-like-mysqls-on-duplicate-key-update

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't support "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE". Look at [Does SQL Server Offer Anything Like MySQL's ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197733/does-sql-server-offer-anything-like-mysqls-on-duplicate-key-update) for the SQL Server recommended SQL.