# INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY: Add values together

Tags: t-sql, insert, sql-update, sql-server-2014, on-duplicate-key

I need to change the date column of an SQL table that contains *dates* and *amounts* from, e.g. `20170101` to `20170102`. However it can be the case that the new date `20170102` already exists. This results in an duplicate key error, because the date column is part of a unique index.

My first thought was to use INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY:

```
INSERT INTO table (Date, Amount)
SELECT '20170102', Amount
FROM table
WHERE Date = '20170101'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Amount = OldAmount + NewAmount
```

The part `Amount = OldAmount + NewAmount` cannot work obviously. But how can I solve my issue?

Comment: The `mysql` and `tsql` tags are, as a rule, incompatible. Please tag your question with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197733/does-sql-server-offer-anything-like-mysqls-on-duplicate-key-update) question help?

Comment: Merge command should get you there

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer: Assume old table TABLE1 ( DATE1 DATE PRIMARY KEY, AMOUNT INT);

1. Add new column Date2 as DATE:

   ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ADD COLUMN DATE2 DATE;
2. Generate all DATE2 by old date;

   UPDATE TABLE1 set DATE2=DATE1; -- OLD column DATE1 or DATE
3. UPDATE DATE2 which record you want to update DATE

   UPDATE TABLE1 SET DATE2='20170101' where DATE1='20170102'; -- Assume 20170101 is already exists
4. Get the records with added amount

   SELECT DATE2,sum(AMOUNT) from TABLE1 group by 1; -- This will show all records with sum
5. You can create new table TABLE2 and insert those records:

   CREATE TABLE TABLE2 ( DATE1 DATE PRIMARY KEY, AMOUNT int);
   INSERT INTO TABLE2 SELECT DATE2, SUM(AMOUNT) FROM TABEL1 GROUP BY 1;

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL server, try a merge statement.

Just to clarify - Do you need to change the dates of records in the table or just add new records?

```
CREATE TABLE #DataTable
(
    SomeDate DATE,
    Amount INT
)

INSERT #DataTable
VALUES
('20170101', 1),
('20170206', 2),
('20170309', 3),
('20170422', 4),
('20170518', 5)

DECLARE @NewValues TABLE
(
    SomeDate DATE,
    Amount INT
)

INSERT @NewValues
VALUES
('20170101', 10), --Update
('20170309', 15), --Update
('20170612', 6), --Insert
('20170725', 7) --Insert

MERGE INTO #DataTable AS tgt
USING @NewValues AS nv
    ON  nv.SomeDate = tgt.SomeDate
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
VALUES
(nv.SomeDate, nv.Amount)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET tgt.Amount = tgt.Amount + nv.Amount
OUTPUT  $action AS MergeAction, 
        Inserted.SomeDate, 
        Deleted.Amount AS OldValue, 
        Inserted.Amount AS NewValue;

DROP TABLE #DataTable;
```