# Update multiple rows into one query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to update multiple rows and same column name with faster way.
Till now i'm using this;

```
Begin Transaction;
Update Inventory set Quantity-=1 where ID=1;
Update Inventory set Quantity-=4 where ID=2;
Update Inventory set Quantity-=1 where ID=1;
Update Inventory set Quantity-=5 where ID=4;
Commit;
```

This method works well, but i dont if it fast to write all the query for each value in same table.Any suggestions?
As i read sql server doesnt support duplicate key update...

Comment: Did you find this in your search https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197733/does-sql-server-offer-anything-like-mysqls-on-duplicate-key-update https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Good point, @P.Salmon. `MERGE` could be applied very nicely.

Comment: You update for ID=1 twice, is it on purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple updates you could use a `CASE` statement:

```
UPDATE Inventory
SET Quantity += CASE ID
    WHEN 1 THEN -1
    WHEN 2 THEN -4
    WHEN 4 THEN -5
    ...
END
WHERE ID IN (1,2,4);
```

However, this would not be efficient for huge updates. In those cases I would prefer 'chunked' `UPDATE` grouped by `ID` values having the same update:

```
UPDATE Inventory
SET Quantity += a
END
WHERE ID IN (X...);

UPDATE Inventory
SET Quantity += b
END
WHERE ID IN (Y...);

...
```

A combination between the two is possible, also.
Good luck.

Comment: But how can i be sure that all executions will succedd if i will not use transaction?@in second example

Comment: I didn't focus on transactions because you ask only about the updates. You can wrap both examples in a transaction. The transaction will ensure that everything within is being executed with appropriate ACID rules applied.