# Inserting and updating records to database at the same time

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a C# console app that needs to insert/update records. At this time, these records are represented by a C# object that looks like this:

```
public class Record
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {

    }
}
```

In my C# code, I have a loop that goes through a `List<Record>`. This loop updates the `Count` if a `Record` with a specific `Id` exists. If a `Record` with the specific `Id` does not exist, I want to add a new `Record`. I might have hundreds of `Record` objects that need to get saved to the database.

Currently, my app is using the [System.Data.SqlClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient?view=netframework-4.7.2). I know how to insert / update records one-at-a-time. However, since I'm saving hundreds of `Record` objects, this approach is slow. I'd like to batch them together and run the SQL once to speed things up.

How do I do that from C# with `System.Data.SqlClient`?

Comment: Sounds like a very common task to me that should have thousands of high quality hits on Google.

Comment: Tried Googling for 'SQL transactions' ?

Comment: This may give you what you are looking for: [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197733/does-sql-server-offer-anything-like-mysqls-on-duplicate-key-update)]