# Trying to use MERGE INTO, resulting in incompatible data types

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL, and trying to make sense of the [Microsoft documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/bb522522(v=sql.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for using the MERGE command.

I found a question here related to what I am doing and I like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30660857/1393894), however when I go to replicate the code in my own table, I have an error.

I made a test table called "First_TEST", Column 1 is named TestCOL1 and has a type text.
In case it matters, the other 4 columns are:
TestCOL2 -type is nchar(10)
TestCOL3 -type is smallint
TestCOL4 -type is bit
TestCOL5 -type is text
(I was playing around with different types as I learned)

My code is as follows:

```sql
MERGE INTO [dbo].[First_TEST] WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target 
USING (SELECT 'TEST' as TestCOL1) AS SOURCE 
(TestCOL1) 
ON (target.TestCOL1 = SOURCE.TestCOL1) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TESTCOL4 = 0 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES (SOURCE.TestCOL1,'2','3','1','LAST');
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

It seems that `target.TestCOL1` is text, as the table is, but `SOURCE.TestCOL1` is defaulting to varchar?

I'm not fluent in SQL, so I'm not sure how to add in a line that would tell `SOURCE.TestCOL1` to be read as text, so the comparison can work. I tried `AS SOURCE (TestCOL1 as text)` but that is giving me a syntax error.

Also in case it changes anything:
For my actual table I will need to compare just one text column to see if it is a duplicate or not,
Update two different columns if it is a duplicate,
Or insert all 20 columns if it is not a duplicate.

Comment: select *
  from #temp_1 a
  inner join #temp_2  b on cast(a.COL1 as varchar(10)) = b.COL1

Comment: The text datatype has been deprecated for 15 years - no one should be using it at this point. Change your table to use varchar(max).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the TEXT Type to VARCHAR(MAX) like below Statement

```
 MERGE INTO [dbo].[First_TEST] WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target 
    USING (SELECT 'TEST' as TestCOL1) AS SOURCE 
    (TestCOL1) 
    ON (Cast(target.TestCOL1 as varchar(max)) = SOURCE.TestCOL1) 
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TESTCOL4 = 0 
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES (SOURCE.TestCOL1,'2','3','1','LAST');
```