# How to determine if given table is memory optimized?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2019

Good morning,

My first question is how to determine if tables created in MS SQL Server are memory optimized. I have some tables and I don't remember if some of them I created in-memory optimized or not.

Many thanks for answers.

Comment: `sys.tables`, `is_memory_optimized`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To riff off of another answer here, here's a way to get the status for *all* tables in your database:

```
select name, OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id,'TableIsMemoryOptimized')
from sys.tables;
```

Similarly, if you want just the in-memory ones, you could do:

```
select name
from sys.tables
where OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id,'TableIsMemoryOptimized') = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

`Select OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('schema.tablename'),'TableIsMemoryOptimized')`

Comment: Unfortunately I faced error message: "Invalid column name 'TableIsMemoryOptimized'." I am using MS SQL Server 2019 Developer.

Comment: I've submitted an edit to the commenter's answer that should make it work for you, @PiotrWojcik. Have a look.

Comment: How to determine if given synonym contains memory optimized table?

Comment: @ZedZip - use the `sys.synonyms` view to find what table the synonym points to and then use the above method to determine if said table is memory-optimized. General advice here though - if you have a separate but related question, it's better to start a new question than to reply to one that's over three years old. You have a better chance of having it answered that way!