# Merge using implicit primary key - like ON DUPLICATE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In MySQL, we can perform an upsert using the ON DUPLICATE KEY clause without knowing or caring what the primary key is.  I would further wager, 99% of all MERGE use cases in SQL Server have the ON clause be ON (source.primary_key = target.primary_key).   So my question is, Is there a way to have the ON clause be implicitly the primary without specifying column(s) of the primary key?

Comment: No.............

Comment: The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is always the best place to get such answers

Comment: _"Is there a way to have the ON clause be implicitly the primary without specifying column(s) of the primary key?"_ - "natural" JOINs using implicit equijoins on implicit columns sounds like a good idea provided you don't think too hard about it - then you realise it's a terrible idea.

Comment: @dai When you argue against making the 99% use case inconvenient.. I think the word is pedantic.

Comment: SQL is confusing enough for most people without adding implicit behaviour... best to be explicit... doesn't really have a downside.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197733/does-sql-server-offer-anything-like-mysqls-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: @kevinc On the contrary: I'm arguing what you're proposing won't make the 99% use-case inconvenient: I'm arguging what you're proposing _will cause users to lose data probably ~20% of the time in the 99% use-case_. Things that are potentially dangerous are inconvenient for a reason. (After all, [MySQL prohibits `UPDATE` and `DELETE` without a PK in the `WHERE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench) clause unless you fiddle with settings, arguably that's even more inconvenient than what we're discussing:

Comment: I suppose you could generate the merge dynamically, but yeah sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: 'In MySQL, we can perform an upsert using the ON DUPLICATE KEY clause without knowing or caring what the primary key' -  not quite ''If you specify an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause and a row to be inserted would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, ' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html - which makes sense if the unique key consists of more than 1 column and differs in all regards from the primary key. put another way mysql will check all unique indexes (including primary)

Comment: Think of the poor microsoft developers, MERGE is buggy enough as it is!

Comment: I cannot believe people are arguing against this - clearly have never used any other competitor rdbms that has this feature (postgres.. mysql..  oracle..) I have **NEVER** coded around  upsert behavior.   Literally "Update the row if it exists" otherwise insert it.  LOADS of additional query traffic if SQL Server doesn't support this.  Now people are going to start arguing why TOP is better than LIMIT lol